# python and mechanize - seeing the options in a select field

Tags: python, mechanize

My html form looks like this:

```
<form name="someform">
     <select name="someid">
          <option value ="option1">
```

I'm trying to see all of the choices and be able to choose them.

I can select the form like this:

```
br.select_form("someform")
```

I can print(br) and see the SelectControl that I want.  If I do:

```
print br["someid"]
```

that's just a list but only contains the first value.  Is there an API for HTMLForm that I can look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to do is to `print br.form`. This prints out ONLY the options in the form. Also, if anything in the form is a dropdown, then the options for that dropdown should also show up.

You could then use `BeautifulSoup` to parse the options.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

Using br.possible_items("someid") gives you the list of options.